# Javascript date objects and Date.prototype customisation

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I am using a calendar plugin, and the plugin has a few callback events allowing you to customise what happens when a user clicks a date etc. One way to set this is up, for me, is the following:

```
onDayClick: function(e) {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.testdomain.com/events/day/' + e.data.date;
}
```

`.date` is a [date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) so, if clicked, for example, this would return:

`http://www.testdomain.com/events/day/Thu Jun 2012 2014 2000:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)`

What I need is the desired output of:

`http://www.testdomain.com/events/day/2014/07/17/` and having a look at the date object documentation, I thought this would be fairly easy.

```
Date.prototype.GetCustomFormat = function() {
    return this.getFullYear()+'/'+getInTwoDigitFormat(this.getMonth())+'/'+getInTwoDigitFormat(this.getDate());
};
function getInTwoDigitFormat(val) {
    return val < 10 ? '0' + val : val;
}

onDayClick: function(e) {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.testdomain.com/events/day/' + e.data.date.GetCustomFormat();
}
```

But, what this brings back, when clicked, is the right year... but the wrong month by 1 and the wrong date by a few days. Weird. So I added some offets and added a UTCMonth...

```
return this.getFullYear()+'/'+getInTwoDigitFormat(this.getUTCMonth()+1)+'/'+getInTwoDigitFormat(this.getDate());
```

This seems to work now. However, if I have an event that lands on the 1st... it uses the 1st from the previous month. So, if I click on 1st July, it returns 1st June.

I think I'm grasping it... but there's a few odd results here and there. Can anyone spot where I am going wrong and put me right?

Thanks

Comment: The strange part is that its brings the wrong day too. The month is expected to by -1 because its zero-indexed.

Comment: Because it's the UTC month, assuming that you're at July 1st _midnight_ in _GMT+0100_, isn't it normal that the UTC month would be one less?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This explanation to this is simple: Because you're one hour *ahead* of UTC, at midnight on the first of July, UTC is still in June! That's why it outputs *June 1st* from using the UTC month. Using the UTC month and not UTC year and date doesn't make much sense, so instead, just use the regular month:

```
Date.prototype.GetCustomFormat = function() {
    return this.getFullYear()+'/'+getInTwoDigitFormat(this.getMonth()+1)+'/'+getInTwoDigitFormat(this.getDate());
};
var testerDate = new Date(Date.parse("Thu Jun 1 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0100"))
testerDate.GetCustomFormat() //The output of this depends on your time zone: It'll be 2012/06/01 if in or ahead of GMT+0100, but otherwise, it'll be 2012/05/31.
```

Comment: You know... I'm sure I had this originally, but it didn't work. But alas it has :) thanks for the reaffirmation.